# Simple Optimize QUery - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using sakila db.

How can I improve the full index scan on country table??

```
select country.country, count(customer_id) as Clients from customer
 INNER JOIN address on customer.address_id = address.address_id
INNER JOIN city on address.city_id = city.city_id
INNER JOIN country on city.country_id = country.country_id
GROUP BY country.country
order by Clients DESC
limit 5;
```

Comment: How big is your `country` table?  There are only 195 countries -- or maybe a few hundred with a broader definition.

Comment: I just want to improve the query in general

Comment: Your query looks fine, although I would indent the code differently.